# How can I do to disable geolocalization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working using react.js and the module useposition but I would like to know how can I do to disable the popup of geolocalization if I go directlry to this path : `http://localhost:3000/activation`

```
import {usePosition} from "use-position";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Activation from "./components/activation/activation";
import {Popup} from "react-leaflet";

const App = () => {
    const { latitude, longitude, timestamp, accuracy, error } = usePosition();

    return (
            <>
                <p>We are there</p>                   
                <Router>
                <Route path="/activate/:token" component={Activation} />
                </Router>
            </>
        );
};

export default App;
```

I mean if I go to this route : `http://localhost:3000/activation` => I don't have the popup of geolocalization

if I go to this route : `http://localhost:3000` => I have the popup of gelolocalization

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `usePosition` only if not in the specified path and use `<Switch>` to only use one of the declared routes:

```js
import {usePosition} from "use-position";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Activation from "./components/activation/activation";
import {Popup} from "react-leaflet";

const WithPosition () => {
    const { latitude, longitude, timestamp, accuracy, error } = usePosition();
    return (
      <div>Whatever rest of contents</div>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <p>We are there</p>                
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/activate/:token" component={Activation} />
                    <Route component={WithPosition} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Actually I always have the popup for the geolocalization when I go to this path `http://localhost:3000/activation`

Comment: Added `Switch` to only render one route.

Comment: It should definitively solve your problem. Any news?

Comment: Thank you, I tried but unfortunately it is like if I only have `<Route component={WithPosition} />` :/

Comment: I've tried this code locally and works as expected: no location popup until navigating outside `/activate/something`. Did you saw the added `<Switch>`?

Comment: Yes I added `<Switch>`... But okay I understood ! Actually when you use `<Switch>` the order is very important ! That's why I got the error ! Now it works perfectly !